# Terrible performance on games on laptop

Tags: graphics-card, performance, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, gaming

I have this computer (specification below) for one year, I am not really a hardcore up-to-date gamer hence my computer. But even I go to games for some fun even for some old ones, it ruins everything.

Perhaps the most annoying **FN: New Vegas**. A 13-year-old game, yet I can not play with a straight 60 FPS, sometimes even it drops to 40s, and it's nonsensical. None of the GPUs are really working for the game (Next to GPU2 (MX350) and MEM1 (Xe)), usages of both are below %50 while computer's fan, battery and game modes are at their highest performance level.

FN New Vegas Screenshot
[image: FN New Vegas Screenshot]

For the these two 2D games (DST and Ozymandias) it is also hard to understand:

Simple, Hex Strategy Game, Ozymandias, Screeshot
[image: Simple, Hex Strategy Game, Ozymandias, Screeshot]

DST Screenshot
[image: DST Screenshot]

Also, for the games that the computer provides little more than the lowest specs (only for GPU), the graphics settings act pretty odd. High -> Medium transition makes no observable difference for the FPS. (Games included: WRC9, Farming Simulator 19, Pure Farming 18, Cities Skylines)

(I could be brutally wrong for this) And as far as it seems to me, if you satisfy the Minimum requirements, it should give at least straight 30 FPS for 1080p Medium or Low. But it almost never happens, *it gets too flickering, going between 40 and 20* continuously. Or if it is to some degree achieved then, as I expressed, it gets stuck at that level and my interventions to Graphic settings gives me no ability to change things.

Cities Skylines Screenshot: Fixed 30 FPS, drops but impossible to increase
[image: Cities Skylines Screenshot: Fixed 30 FPS, drops but impossible to increase]

Pure Farming 18 Screenshot: GPUs are not actively used, graphic adjustments futile,
onlthe Iris Xe gives consistent 30 FPS
[image: Pure Farming 18 Screenshot: GPUs are not actively used, graphic adjustments futile, onlthe Iris Xe gives consistent 30 FPS]

It looks like some driver issue or heat prevention mechanism that prevents GPU and CPU to be used normally, maybe because 14" body/chassis. Last year it impressed me with The Witcher 3 and Bioshock Remastered performance, but even at there, like after some minutes the performance was dropping significantly.

**Lenovo V2 G14 ITL** - 14"

- **CPU**: i5 1135g7 2.4 GHz -
- **GPU**: Nvidia MX350 2 GB (Equivalent of 950M-960M) -
- **RAM**: 16 GB 3200 MHz -
- **Integrated**: Iris Xe 2 GB(?) -
- **Screen**: 60 Hz -
- Windows 10 Pro
- (RAM newly upgraded, thermal paste renewed, both made no change)

Comment: If performance starts well and then drops suddenly, as you suggest mentioning you played Witcher last year, then your problem is cooling. Either you need to open your system up and clean out the dust from the heatsinks and fans, or you may need to replace the thermal pads on your CPU/GPU. Potentially the cooling on your CPU/GPU is simply not up to the job, as the smaller the laptop the more difficult it is to cool properly.

Comment: It flip-flopping between 20 and 40 FPS is also a sign of poor cooling. It means that it runs well for a moment, heats up, starts throttling due to heat, cools down and starts performing well again and then producing more heat again in a continuous cycle.

Comment: Why are you expecting high performance out of mobile GPU from 4 generations ago and a low end iGPU with worse performance than the mobile GPU?  I see no reason you should expect high performance from DX9 based on the hard you have. If you have both Intel and Nvidia drivers installed that could actually be working against you.

Comment: I forgot to mention drive, currently I am playing on HP S650 SSD of 500-450 w-r, not the best, but it should not make these up. Also, I played on rather better main SSD (2242) of the laptop but, was not so different. Additionally, I am not playing modern AAA games, am I? Expecting 60 FPS on DST, Ozymandias or a 13-year-old game should not be regarded as an expectation of high performance. Maybe I don't know about laptops and their temperature system.

Comment: I don't know, I rely mostly on the requirements presented by the developers, so those 3 mobile game level games are requiring almost no GPU ("Graphics Card: AMD Radeon X1300" and alike) for today's standards.

Comment: Yes, you're correct about the system requirements and the games you're running *should* perform better, indeed. IMO, Mokubai has the correct idea.